# Can't compile tiny C code which uses librsvg

Tags: c, glib, code-blocks, cairo

I am almost complete noob in linux world and I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with gnome-session-fallback (compiz) under VirtualBox on Windows 8.1 machine. My goal is to use this library:
https://github.com/akrinke/svg2cairo

The only thing I need is to compile 'svg2cairoxml.c'. Here is very simplified version of this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <librsvg/rsvg.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use Code::Blocks 13.12 and Anjuta 3.10.2 with no success. Both of them producing error "fatal error: librsvg/rsvg.h: No such file or directory" on compilation. I managed to find this file under another location: 'librsvg-2.0/librsvg/rsvg.h'. So I changed 3rd line of the code above. Later I installed gtk dev library following stackoverflow answer. And then I encountered error which I can't resolve: "fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory" in the file 'rsvg.h':

```
// this is line 31
#include <glib-object.h>
```

I also located this file, the real path is 'glib-2.0\glib-object.h'. But the thing is 'rsvg.h' is protected so I can't change it. And this is where i'm stuck.

Also I found this instructions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537008/compilation-error-while-using-librsvg
But those are too complicated for noob like me.

I think my goal (to compile the only small 'svg2cairoxml.c' file) is pretty easy for experienced linux programmers. So can someone please help me to do it? Also I guess I'm doing something wrong like using wrong version of libraries or something like this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit any of the .h files - it's a matter of adding the appropriate **include paths** to your Code::Blocks project configuration equivalent to adding `-I/usr/include/librsvg-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/` to the compiler commandline.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I also installed necessary 'librsvg2*' packages from software center.

Comment: the compile step needs to have (for gcc compiler) parameters of the '-Ipathtoheaderfile' variety.  Then when the compile has no errors/warnings (enable all warnings and correct them)  then the link step needs a combination of two parameters: 1) '-Lpathtolibrary' and 2) '-llibname'  where '-l is a lowercase L and libname is the library name without the leading 'lib' nor the trailing .so or .a  I.E. libmath.so would be included via '-lmath'

Comment: Try compiling from the command-line using `gcc svg2cairoxml.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs librsvg-2.0\``: if that works, then it is just a matter of modifying your IDE's settings accordingly.

Comment: "gcc svg2cairoxml.c..." command produces "a.out" which actually works printing program usage. So I just need to know my IDE better. Thank you both for so quickly and useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a development package installs its header and/or library files in places that are not directly on the standard compiler search path, you need to specify the locations yourself explicitly. To do that on the `gcc` command line for example, you would use suitable `-I` (include path) and `-L` (library path) directives. You also need to tell the linker which specific libraries to link from those search paths using `-l` directives such as `-lrsvg-2` for librsvg-2.

Since paths and libraries can become quite complex, and vary depending on the exact platform, some development packages provide a *package configuration* (`.pc`) file that can be interrogated by the `pkg-config` utility to generate the appropriate directives at build time. The `librsvg-dev` package is one such, so to build your simple program on the command-line all that's required is

```
gcc svg2cairoxml.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs librsvg-2.0`
```

To achieve the same within your IDE, you have a couple of options: you can either run

```
pkg-config --cflags librsvg-2.0
```

and

```
pkg-config --libs librsvg-2.0
```

in a terminal and copy the resulting output into the appropriate compiler and linker settings boxes or, following this answer to a similar question on StackOverflow [How to setup GTK+ to develop with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921798), add the `pkg-config` command substitutions directly to the <kbd>Other options</kbd> tab as follows:

[image: Code::Blocks pkg-config --cflags setting]

[image]

Comment: Wow, you wrote an article to answer the question. Thanks a lot, steeldriver.